# Pandas to Oracle Database - encoding for umlaute

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas

I am using python 3.6 to read some xml data and store it in a pandas.Dataframe. The data contains strings with Umlaute which are printed correctly within python.

My connection to the Oracle database is created as follows:

```
config.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
es = "oracle://" + schema + ":" + schema + "@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (FAILOVER=ON) (CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " + host + ")(PORT = " + port + ")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = " + service + ")))"
engine = create_engine(es, encoding= config.encoding)
con = engine.connect()
df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists = 'replace')
```

I tried 2 ways to write the data into the database:

1) without direct encoding I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...", line 59, in <module>
df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists = 'replace')
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 473, in to_sql
chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1156, in to_sql
table.insert(chunksize)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 670, in insert
self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 645, in _execute_insert
conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
context)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.reraise(*exc_info)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1170, in _execute_context
context)
File "D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 852, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

2) I encoded every relevant entry using str.encode(config.encoding). In this case I don't get an error, but the Umlaute don't seem to be stored properly. When reading them again using the same connection and pandas.from_sql(...) the output looks as follows:

```
status
Erf?llt
```

Also when looking at the database using SQLDeveloper or Data Grip, the Umlaute are shown as question marks.

The database Setup looks like this:

```
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   12.1.0.2.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8ISO8859P15
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer based on a similar problem.

before creating the connection / the engine I set the NLS_LANG to the settings of the database:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1'
```

This avoids a transformation made by cx_oracle which causes the error.